# How to make table row clickable and highlight it by bringing it to front visually?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to create a table with the following two functionalities:

1. Some kind of 'bring-to-front with shadow' or '3d effect' that I see in some websites and find very pleasant.
2. Mouse cursor should have the 'hand' icon indicating the row is clickable.

I need these functionalities to appear whenever the user hover over the rows of the table. I tried using Bootstrap 4's `table-hover` class's functionality but couldn't achieve any of the two functionalities.

For the first functionality, I have an idea of adding a class with shadow to the `<tr>` being hovered. Don't know however, if this is the best approach. **Is there some already defined class that could achieve such behavior?**

And for the second functionality, I have no idea. Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <thead id="thead_st" class="thead">
      <tr>
        <th class="thead-row" scope="col"></th>
        <th class="thead-row" scope="col">1</th>
        <th class="thead-row" scope="col">2</th>
        <th class="thead-row" scope="col">3</th>
        <th class="thead-row" scope="col">4</th>
        <th class="thead-row" scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="trow">
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td class="score">4.7</td>
        <td>Bla bla</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table-wrapper {
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
   margin-top: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 0px;
}

body {
   background: #ECEEF1;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   color: #2C3A56;
}

tr {
  font-size: 16.5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

td, th {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

#thead_st {
  background-color: #F6CE52;
  border: 3px solid #F6CE52;
  color: white;
}

.thead-row {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
}


.trow:hover {
   cursor:pointer; //set the cursor to pointer (hand)
   background-color: blue; //sets hovered row's background color to blue
   box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check Below Fiddle. Your two requirement completed.

1. Some kind of 'bring-to-front with shadow' or '3d effect' that I see in some websites and find very pleasant.
2. Mouse cursor should have the 'hand' icon indicating the row is clickable.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/hptpcb1d/)

```
.trow
{
   transition: transform .2s;
}

.trow:hover {
   cursor:pointer; 
   transform: scale(1.03);
   background:#ccc;
   color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In css, assuming your `<tr>` has `.row` class :

```
.row:hover{
   cursor:pointer; //set the cursor to pointer (hand)
   background-color:blue; //sets hovered row's background color to blue
   box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888; //this is a box shadowing effect that you can tweak at your choice.
}
```

If further more you just want to make that "3D" effect you can play with `width` and `height` properties of the `<tr>` element to make it bigger over the others on `hover` event.

When I used to play with 3D effects I usually implemented [2D Transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) to adjust positioning with translation properties.

Comment: The cursor functionality worked, but the shadow and background didn't. Could you take a look at my HTML/CSS code that I just added at the edit and see what's wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/17xo9wo7/ this fiddle works. I just copied your code and deleted the // comments that you copied from my answer. You just need to tweak the values